# Javascript Object.defineProperty() for newebies

Tags: javascript

I need to create a property of an element with no id. Here's what i mean:

```
var createdElement = document.createElement('div');
Object.defineProperty(createdElement, 'id', 'someId');
```

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question. Are you looking for a tutorial? Is there a specific thing you've tried to accomplish that hasn't worked? If so, how?

Comment: Take a look at [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty): if you're using defineProperty you need to pass a descriptor object (`{value: x, enumerable: true}`), not just the property value. If you just want to set the property value, you can do a standard property assignment (`x.y = z`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## First Way

You can do this using .createElement() from Javascript. So you dont need Object.defineProperty().

Here it is at use:

```
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
btn.setAttribute("id", "uniqueIdentifier");
```

---

## Second Way

You can also set ID by the .Id() like this for example:

***HTML***

```
<div class="abc"></div>
<div class="abc"></div>
```

***JS***

```
var abcElements = document.querySelectorAll('.abc');

// Set their ids
for (var i = 0; i < abcElements.length; i++){
    abcElements[i].id = 'abc-' + i;
}
```

This will assign the ID 'abc-' to each element. So it would come out like this:

```
<div class="abc" id="abc-0"></div>
<div class="abc" id="abc-1"></div>
```

---

## Comments on your Question

By the way learn to write a better topic title [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title).

Comment: the negativity of ones and the helpfulness of others. thanks

Comment: No Problem @Toffer any time!

Comment: `var = ` is invalid JavaScript.

Comment: Using `setAttribute` is odd. Just assigning to properties (if available, like `.id` is in this case) is the best practice.

Comment: @Gary Missed it there sorry

Comment: @Toffer Edited the anwser, take a look at the other way that Bergi Proposed!

Answer (score 1):

Strictly responding to your question, the way you used is malformed. Should be something like this:

```
var createdElement = document.createElement('div');
Object.defineProperty(createdElement, 'id', {
  value:'someId',
  enumerable: true,
  writable: true
});
```

That's said, it's a totally weird way to achieve what you want. You can simply do:

```
var createdElement = document.createElement('div');
createdElement.id = 'someId';
```